# Help me to translate this Japanese phrase

Tags: translation, kanji

[image: Phrase I am translating]

Greetings,

So this is what I am trying to translate. The problem is that the last character doesn't want to show up in any Kanji recognition, so I have two questions:

1. Does the last Kanji character from the image exists?
2. What is the translation of this phrase?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but it seems that they just confused vertical and horizontal lines and the correct kanji would be 傷 (wound, hurt, injury).
In this case the translation would be something like "storm wound" \ "storm damage". Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, that does make sense. It's understandable in a way, as a learner of Chinese, I'd say, characters with lots of strokes aren't easy to write without mistakes. Let's see if others have more opinions on the matter.